# Is the virtual particle-antiparticle pair in vacuum entangled or a superposition?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

It's usually claimed that the virtual particle-antiparticle pair in vacuum can be understood as entangled particles.

Can we also regard them as eigen states with different energies of a certain field in spacetime? If this is true, then the particle-antiparticle pair can then be regarded as a superposition of these states.

I ask this question since recently L. Susskind talked about a similar issue in ***[this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.02589)*** about the double-slit experiment, where he regarded the photons passing through different slits as 'entangled' instead of 'superpositioned'.

Abstract of paper cited.

> Copenhagen vs Everett, Teleportation, and ER=EPR https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.02589
>
> Quantum gravity may have as much to tell us about the foundations and interpretation of quantum mechanics as it does about gravity. The Copenhagen interpretation of quantum mechanics and Everett's Relative State Formulation are complementary descriptions which in a sense are dual to one another. My purpose here is to discuss this duality in the light of the of ER=EPR conjecture.